# What's the difference between "keymap" and "shortcut"?

Tags: visual-studio-code, pycharm, ide

When I was using some IDEs, I found two different things that seem to mean the same thing. They are "keymap" and "shortcut", so what is the difference between them?

Answer (score 3):

As per my understanding, `Every shortcut will have keymap`. To have a shortcut, you need to map one or more keys to it. Shortcut is `what` and keymap is `how`.

Let us say you want to clear your terminal using Ctrl+K. Then `Clear` is your shortcut and `Ctrl+K` is your keymap.